# Treat escaped newline as line continuation

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, escaping, boost-spirit

Here is an example of the syntax -- two groups of items:

```
I_name m_name parameter1=value parameter2=value
I_name m_name parameter1=value \
parameter2=value
```

My question is how to define the skip-type.
It is not just space_type but space_type minus newline.
But newline followed by backslash is a skip-type.

E.g.
I define name like that:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> m_sName;

m_sName %= qi::lexeme[ascii::alpha >> *ascii::alnum];
```

This is obviously not correct, as the space_type must include newline-backslash.

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char_class.html#spirit.qi.reference.char.char_class.expression_semantics) may help.

Answer (score 1):

The following grammar works for me.

```
*("\\\n" | ~qi::char_('\n')) % '\n'
```

It will ignore any newline after the backslash. And the following is a simple test.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE example
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

typedef std::vector<std::string> Lines;

inline auto ParseLines(std::string const& str) {
    Lines lines;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    if (qi::parse(
        str.begin(), str.end(),
        *("\\\n" | ~qi::char_('\n')) % '\n',
        lines)) {
        return lines;
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Parse error at ParseLines");
    }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestParseLines) {
    std::string const str =
        "I_name m_name parameter1=value parameter2=value\n"
        "I_name m_name parameter1 = value \\\n"
        "parameter2 = value";
    Lines const expected{
        "I_name m_name parameter1=value parameter2=value",
        "I_name m_name parameter1 = value parameter2 = value"
    };
    BOOST_TEST(ParseLines(str) == expected);
}
```

You should use "`-std=c++14 -lboost_unit_test_framework`" for compilation. Anyway, it is easy to convert the code for c++03.

Answer (score 0):

`qi::blank` is exactly that. It's `qi::space` without newlines.

You can do this too: `("\\\n" | qi::blank)`

To be able to declare a rule *with such a skipper*, define a skipper grammar:

```
template <typename It>
   struct my_skipper : qi::grammar<It> {
       my_skipper() : my_skipper::base_type(start) {}
       qi::rule<It> start = ("\\\n" | qi::blank);
   };
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1943586536033c54)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace ast {
    struct record {
        std::string iname, mname;
        std::map<std::string, std::string> params;
    };

    using records = std::vector<record>;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::record, iname, mname, params)

template <typename It>
struct my_parser : qi::grammar<It, ast::records()> {
    using Skipper = qi::rule<It>;

    my_parser() : my_parser::base_type(start) {
        skipper = ("\\\n" | qi::blank);
        name    = +qi::graph;
        key     = +(qi::graph - '=');
        param   = key >> '=' >> name;
        record  = name >> name >> *param;
        records = *(record >> +qi::eol);
        start   = qi::skip(qi::copy(skipper)) [ records ];
    }

  private:
    Skipper skipper;
    qi::rule<It, ast::records(), Skipper> records;
    qi::rule<It, ast::record(),  Skipper> record;
    qi::rule<It, ast::records()> start;
    qi::rule<It, std::pair<std::string, std::string>()>  param;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>  name, key;
};

int main() {
#if 1
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    It f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;
#else
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    std::string const input = "something here a=1\n";
    It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
#endif

    ast::records data;
    bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, my_parser<It>(), data);
    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed:\n";
        for (auto& r : data) {
            std::cout << "\t" << r.iname << " " << r.mname;
            for (auto& p : r.params)
                std::cout << " [" << p.first << ": " << p.second << "]";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints (for the input in your question):

```
Parsed:
    I_name m_name [parameter1: value] [parameter2: value]
    I_name m_name [parameter1: value] [parameter2: value]
```

Comment: Added a full demo, without a separate skipper grammar [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1943586536033c54)

Comment: Thanks! Works great!